# The getProcessing() function execution dont stops

Tags: python

I have this code below where I show a option menu.

If user choose option 2, it executes the function getProcessing(), and it is working fine.

The only problem is that when the getProcessing function is executed I want to stop the execution of this function and show again the option menu. But this isnt working, the getProcessing() function execution dont stops.

I tried to put return False, but still dont works.

Do you see why this can be happening?

```
def getProcessing():
    # from processing.py file import createmrjob function
    from processing import createmrjob
    return False

def nav():
    print ""
    while True:
        response_options = {'1': Choice(msg="User Managment", callback=userManagment), '2': Choice(msg="Processing Files", callback=getProcessing)}
        result = make_choice(response_options)
        if result is None:
            print "Selected option not available."
            print ""
        else:
            result.callback()

def make_choice(optiontable):
    for resp, choiceobj in (sorted(optiontable.items())):   
        print("{} - {}".format(resp, choiceobj.msg))
    print ""
    usr_resp = raw_input("Select an option: ")
    print ""
    return optiontable.get(usr_resp, None)
```

When the status is = COMPLETED in the function below I want to show the message "Completed job", but what Im getting is the line `print status.state`, so it always showing a message "COMPLETED" and dont exit this while loop to show "Completed job".

```
def createmrjob(dict):  
    emr = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
    print ""
    bucket = dict['bucket']
    step = StreamingStep(name='Max Temperature',
    mapper=dict['mapper'],
    reducer=dict['reducer'],
    input=dict['datafile'],
    output='s3n://'+bucket+'/uploadedfiles/')
    jobid = emr.run_jobflow(name="Data Processing", 
    log_uri="s3://"+bucket+"/uploadedfiles/erm_logs/",
    steps=[step],
    num_instances = 1,
    )

    print "Job flow submited with success, waiting for job flow to complete..."

    status = emr.describe_jobflow(jobid)    
    print status.state
    while status.state != 'COMPLETED' or status.state != 'FAILED':      
        status = emr.describe_jobflow(jobid)
        print status.state
    print ""
    print "Job status:" + str(status.state)
    print ""
    print "Completed Job"
    print ""
```

Comment: We need more context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I update my question wtih more details!

Comment: Is it me, or, you're never calling createmrjob ?

Comment: I call when user choose option 2 -> '2': Choice(msg="Processing Files", callback=getProcessing). I have this function getProcessing that calls createmrjob from other file .py.

Comment: No you're importing it, not calling it.

Comment: So how I can do this? It is working. Im getting the issue Im describing in question but it seems that the function is called.

Comment: I insist you never call `createmrjob`, if it's executed, it's from code that is not displayed here, so we can't help. You better throw in it to get a stacktrace to spot the real caller.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think I have all the important code here. Im showing a menu options and when user choose option 2 I have the callback to call the function getProcessing. And this function getProcessing imports other function createmrjob from other python file.